# How to get new gmaps styles?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

When I created a simple google map I get map like this

[image: Old map]

but in https://www.google.com.ua/maps/ map is looking like this

[image]

How to get a new design of gmaps?

I guess I need a JSON styles, but can`t find official JSON styles from map.

code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
  /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
   * element that contains the map. */
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
  /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
</style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="map"></div>
   <script>
     var map;
     function initMap() {
       map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
         center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 8
      });
    }
  </script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

And here official demo (old design)
https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/map-simple

from jsfiddle
[image]

Comment: How are you loading your "simple google map"?  Anything I look at with the Google Maps Javascript API v3 looks more similar to the bottom picture than the top.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @geocodezip all code from here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Comment: The [tiles I get from that code](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/enwpc595/2/) (modified to change the location to one close to the images posted) still look more like the second image than the first.

Comment: Not for me. Added new screenshot

Comment: That screenshot still looks more like the second one than the first.

Comment: no, another colors, icons, fonts

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom style here https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/ and export as a JSON file. The tool gives you the opportunity to declare styles to a granular level

Other options are https://snazzymaps.com/ or http://www.mapstylr.com/ to use any of the existing styles or create yours.